# push docker image to container registry with private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I have a container registry (CR) where one of our IT guys has set a private endpoint, which I think means, that the CR is only visible in our company network? When I try:

```
acr login --name amazingCR1234
```

I get:

```
Looks like you don't have access to registry 'amazingCR1234.azurecr.io'. To see configured firewall rules, run 'az acr show --query networkRuleSet --name amazingCR1234'. To see if public network access is enabled, run 'az acr show --query publicNetworkAccess'. Please refer to https://aka.ms/acr/errors#connectivity_forbidden_error for more information.
```

I am a bit confused. How can I now deploy my docker image, which I could previously? Thanks.

Comment: how did you set private endpoint?

Comment: Private endpoint made ACR available in your VNET, and now the question is if you have access via VPN to that VNET, or not. If not then - this is the reason why you can't push image to ACR.

Comment: Thanks. I think the reason is that my Azure VM, which I use to develop, is part of a different subscription than my ACR?

Comment: Can I please ask . Do 2 subscriptions imply 2 VNs (even if they share same AAD)? I think this is the issue? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the message you gave that your VM, which you want to use to access the ACR, is in the different subscriptions from the VNet that the ACR private endpoint in. In this situation, you can try to peer the two different VNet, even if they are in the different subscriptions. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-subscriptions) are the steps that how to peer two VNets in the different subscriptions.

Comment: thanks. yes I gathered this last night as well. I raise with IT.